# How to fetch preceding ids on fly using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id':[11,11,11,12,12,12],
                   'test_date':['02/03/2012 10:24:21','05/01/2019 10:41:21','12/13/2011 11:14:21','10/11/1992 11:14:21','02/23/2002 10:24:21','07/19/2005 10:24:21'],
                   'original_enc':['A742','B963','C354','D563','J323','G578']})

hash_file = pd.DataFrame({'source_enc':['A742','B963','C354','D563','J323','G578'],
                          'hash_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

cols = ["subject_id","test_date","enc_id","previous_enc_id"]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
test_df.head()
```

I would like to do two things here

1. Map `original_enc` to their corresponding `hash_id` and store it in `enc_id`
2. Find the previous `hash_id` for each subject based on their current `hash_id` and store it in `previous_enc_id`

I tried the below

```
test_df['subject_id'] = df['subject_id']
test_df['test_date'] = df['test_date']
test_df['enc_id'] = df['original_enc'].map(hash_file)
test_df = test_df.sort_values(['subject_id','test_date'],ascending=True)
test_df['previous_enc_id'] = test_df.groupby(['subject_id','test_date'])['enc_id'].shift(1)
```

However, I don't get the expected output for the `previous_enc_id` column as it is all `NA`.

I expect my output to be like as shown below. You see `NA` in the expected row for the 1st row of every subject because that's their 1st encounter. There is no info to look back to.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only one column for `groupby`:

```
test_df['previous_enc_id'] = test_df.groupby('subject_id')['enc_id'].shift()
```